# How to mock static method available in abstract class which returns servlet context using spring based unit test

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

I want to mock static method which passes
`UtilityThreadLocal.getServletContext()` as a parameter to `webApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext (UtilityThreadLocal.getServletContext())).`

I want to use easy mock + powermock. I am probaly tring to create mock from xml and autowring those in my test class but not able to do such. Here is my code which is not working properly. It returning `Null pointer exception` and sometime Illegal state exception

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@PrepareForTest({
    WebApplicationContextUtils.class
})
public class LoginServiceTest {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @Test
    public void loginTest() throws Exception {
        String[] rights = new String[] {
        "MANAGE_TENANTS", "MANAGE_USERS", "MANAGE_APPLICATIONS", "MANAGE_SETTINGS", "MANAGE_HISTORY", "MANAGE_OFFICES", "EXPORT_TIMESHEETS", "MANAGE_POLICIES", "MANAGE_ASSETS", "MANAGE_LEAVES"
        };
        Role roleObj = new Role();
        roleObj.setRights(rights);
        WebApplicationContext webAppContextMock = createNiceMock(WebApplicationContext.class);
        RoleService roleServiceBeanMock = createNiceMock(RoleService.class);
        PowerMock.mockStatic(WebApplicationContextUtils.class);
        expect(WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(UtilityThreadLocal.getServletContext())).andReturn(webAppContextMock);
        expect(webAppContextMock.getBean(RoleService.class)).andReturn(roleServiceBeanMock);
        expect(roleServiceBeanMock.get((long) 2).getRights()).andReturn(rights);
        expect(roleObj.getRights()).andReturn(roleObj.getRights());
        PowerMock.replay(WebApplicationContextUtils.class);
        replay(webAppContextMock);
        replay(roleServiceBeanMock);
    }
}
```

Comment: With powermock you can mock static methods but you probably shouldn't unless it's legacy or unavailable for refactoring code. @Abhish you need to clarify your question

Comment: i want to mock this.rights = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(UtilityThreadLocal.getServletContext()).getBean(RoleService.class).get(user.getRoleId()).getRights(); but when i try to mock getWebApplicationContext it returns Null

Answer (score 0):

Mock the call to `getWebApplicationContext` like this

```
expect(WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
           EasyMock.anyObject(ServletContext.class)))
   .andReturn(webAppContextMock);
```

This uses non strict matching that is call with any parameter will return specified value. You may probably change setup of other mocks so that they actually match the parameters.

Comment: I want to mock enire row WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(UtilityThreadLocal.getServle‌​tContext()).getBean(RoleService.class).get(user.getRoleId()).getRights(); which returns string array of rights

Comment: You can't mock entire row. You can mock single call. But the test you show tries to do that namely mock each call in that row separately. The problem you get is caused by incorrect mocking that is one of the mocks doesn't work (due to incorrect input parameter I guess) so that's why I wrote last suggestion. In this case easymock returns null value. Debug your code under test and find which method invocation returns null. That would be incorrectly mocked method which you should fix.

Comment: Tried to debug my code the line WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
           EasyMock.anyObject(ServletContext.class)) itself returning Null

Comment: I also tried to pass ServletContext Mock object in place of ServletContext.class but still returning Null

Comment: You should not debug the test itself. You need to debug actual code that invokes your mocks and see which invocation returns null instead of value you setup in mock.